# Get Firestore generated doc ID after set

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to get the generated doc Id after you've saved a document to firestore?

```
var collection = db.collection("Users").doc();
collection.set({
                  xxx:"stuff",
                  yyy:"stuff"
               })
                .then(function (?Something?) 
                  {
                    var theIdIWant = ?Something?;
                  }
               )
```

[image]

Edit: Or just

```
var myID = collection.id
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return value from [doc()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) is a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) which has the unique id in its [id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#id) field.

```
var doc = db.collection("Users").doc();
doc.set({
    xxx:"stuff",
    yyy:"stuff"
})
.then(() => { 
    var theIdIWant = doc.id
})
```